# Retrieve unique results with Core Data, NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I need to be able to do the equivalent of the following SQL using Core Data:

`SELECT DISTINCT(foo) FROM bar`

Is there a way of doing this with NSPredicate? Or any other way for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do is add this to your NSFetchRequest

```
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```

Comment: Have tried that without much luck. Still returns the full set.